# The number of positive integral solutions to the system of equations.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

> The number of positive integral solutions to the system of equations
>
> $$\begin{align} & a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4}+a_{5}=47\\
> &a_{1}+a_{2}=37,\ \ \{a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4},a_{5}\} \in \mathbb{N}\end{align}$$
>
> is

$a.)\ 2044\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad b.)\ 2246\\
c.)\ 2024\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \color{green}{d.)\ 2376}$

I know my something like stars and bars for $a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4}+a_{5}=47$ ,

the non-negative solutions are $\dbinom{47+4}{4}$ and

for $a_{1}+a_{2}=37$

the non-negative solutions are $\dbinom{37+1}{1}$

But the non-negative solutions will include zero and it is not needed here.

Also there are two cases combined I am confused on how to solve this question.

Also this question was given in chapter quadratic equations I don't know how.

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade.Thanks.

Comment: Consider that $a_3 + a_4 + a_5 = 10$.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is no correct option.

The system is equivalent to 
$$a_1+a_2=37$$
$$a_3+a_4+a_5=10$$

Let $b_i=a_i-1$. Then, $b_i$ are non-negative integers. So, the system is equivalent to
$$b_1+b_2=37-2=35$$
$$b_3+b_4+b_5=10-3=7$$
Then, here you can use the method you wrote, so we have
$$\binom{36}{1}\times\binom{9}{2}=\color{red}{1296}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You can look up "stars and bars" to find the formula for positive integer solutions (or just use the formula for non-negative solutions, by adding 1 automatically to each number and then subtracting the number of numbers from the sum, and using your formula for non-negative solutions for the lowered sum). Then, you have a solution if and only if $a_1 + a_2 = 37$ and $a_3 + a_4 + a_5 = 10$, and these events are independent.

Comment: u mean $38+\dbinom{12}{2}$ ?, didn't understand ur hint.

Comment: @RK I'm not sure if I understand your question, but basically what I'm saying is that the number of positive integer solutions, for example, of $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 = 47$ is equal to the number of non-negative solutions to $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 = 47 - 5 = 42$.

Comment: @RK Also, I should have been more clear, by "independent" I mean you can multiply the number of solutions for $a_1 + a_2$ with the number of solutions for $a_3 + a_4 + a_5$.

Comment: is this correct $\dbinom{46}{4}\times \dbinom{36}{1}$ ???

Answer (score 1):

$$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=47\\a_1+a_2=37\\
\left\{\begin{matrix}
a_3+a_4+a_5=47-37\\ 
a_1+a_2=37
\end{matrix}\right. $$ multiply those answers $$ \binom{37+2-1}{2-1}*\binom{10+3-1}{3-1}\\=\binom{38}{1}*\binom{12}{2}$$